# Simple "Foreach" Issue

Tags: c#, foreach

I am getting an error in visual studio.  I have defined grade and grades to be something, correct? What is so wrong about my usage of this `foreach` statement?

Full code follows:

```
namespace GradesStr8 {    
    class GradeBook {

        float passgrade = 70;
        foreach (float grade in grades) {

    }

        public void AddGrade(float grade) {    
            grades.Add(grade);    
        }

        List<float> grades = new List<float>();    
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing looping inside the class. Why? Shouldn't the loop be inside one of your functions ?

Comment: loop can be only inside property, method, constructor...

Comment: @rcs is right, in class you define properties and actions not loop. Take this loop inside any method

Comment: *Please mark one of the answers as "Correct Answer" if you find them working (which they all are)

Answer (score 3):

You can't write function code in a class without a function wrapping.
Well at-least not in this form.

You need to ask yourself what this function needs to do? what do you want from this loop? is it the sum all the grades and give you an answer? average?
If this is the case then you will probably looking for this kind of implementation:

*Note: you might find LINQ easier to use, but for now let's look at a basic implementation

```
class GradeBook
{
    private readonly List<float> _grades;
    private const float PASSGRADE = 70;

    public GradeBook()
    {
        _grades = new List<float>();
    }

    public void AddGrade(float grade)
    {
        _grades.Add(grade);
    }

    //Your new function
    public float Sum()
    {
        float sum = 0;
        foreach (float grade in _grades)
        {
            sum += grade;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    //Your new function Avg
    public float Avg()
    {
        if(_grades.Count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        float sum = Sum();
        return sum/_grades.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: sum of grades? maybe avg will be more relevant ?

Comment: *Added AVG implementation also

Answer (score 0):

Any loop must be contained in a class member such as a function. You can not write a loop directly in the class.
Your actual code should have been like:

```
public class GradeBook{
    float PassGrade = 70;

    public void FunctionWithLoop(){
        foreach(var grade in grades){
             //Some code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working now, thank you! Although I don't fully understand why it must be that way...

Answer (score 0):

You can't write foreach loop in class definition without function!

let say if your purpose to print all the grades you will do it like that..

```
namespace GradesStr8 {    
    class GradeBook {

        List<float> grades = new List<float>();
        float passgrade = 70;    

publuc void PrintGrades()
{

        foreach (float grade in grades) {
        Console.WriteLine(grade);
    }
}

        public void AddGrade(float grade) {    
            grades.Add(grade);    
        }
    }
}
```

in this case when i create instance of my class (object) `GradeBook book = new GradeBook();`

i will have functions ():

```
book.PrintGrades() // will print all the grades.

book.AddGrade(75); // will add grade to the list.
```

if you could do foreach without function you simple would not be able to invoke it.

you need to remamber that c# it OOP language. (if you need foreach for program process and not specific method you can use it in Main (that also function..))

for example:

```
namespace GradesStr8
{
    class GradeBook
    {
        public List<float> grades { get; set; }
        private const float passgrade = 70;

        public GradeBook()
        {
            grades = new List<float>();
        }

        public void AddGrade(float grade)
        {
            grades.Add(grade);
        }
    }

    public class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            GradeBook book = new GradeBook();
            book.grades.Add(75);
            book.grades.Add(46);

            foreach (float grade in book.grades)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(grade);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you need to read ([Essential C# 6.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134141040))

Comment: Why must I write it within a function? I'm a little lost on some of these terms, could you possibly break down the reason I'm not able to simply write it within my class?